# Nativescript or Native in my use case

Tags: android, ios, native, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

I must develop a ios/android app, i'm not sure witch is the best way to go.

80% of the app it's no problem to dev with NativeScript.

This features are:

- Profile
- Settings
- Wiki
- Statistics
- Support
- ...

but the 20% of the app is a 2d game.

This is my first app for both platforms (ios, i have experience), i'm not sure witch is the best approach.

My thoughts are this, it is a cool idea to dev in Nativescript and have only one code base but in the future it's possible that this is a negative point.

Or is there a other way to go?

Thanks for all thoughts

Comment: Well, Nativescript not is a framework to make 2d games. I don't know if 2 native apps are going to do it better, maybe you can search for a game engine. Could you tell us if the 2d game uses heavy grafics? Do you have experience with Javascript / Css?

Comment: No the graphic is not heavy is like a old school arcade game. Yes i have huge experience in js/css, this is the reason whi i have looked at NativeScript.

Comment: The benefit of NativeScript is that you can still use native code in the future, so you could make 2 native implementations for 1 page.

Comment: Yes that is clear and i like this idea, but me is not clear how can i dev the game in NativeScript. I found this [article](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/first-steps-in-game-dev-with-nativescript) but me is not clear where is this rendered in a webview or by the gpu, i don't know and how performant is this implementation

Comment: NativeScript renders UIs with the native platform’s rendering engine—no WebViews—resulting in native-like performance and UX. [reference](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-0)

Comment: thanks for your help, now what you prefere for my use case, i think on the long view its better to create native versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to be honest, i do prefer to do everything in NativeScript, and like you mentioned almost 80% of you application is going to be in NativeScript and with it, you have the following :

1 - it is truly native, you can call Native API directly from the SDK, and also from 3rd party libraries (any 3rd party library you want), something will be easy and feels and taste the same way as any called "native" app will do.

2 - Cross platform application ( just think of how much time you will take is you go with "Native" path)

3 - Developing a Game beneath an app, is actually easy using nativescript and typescript ( in case you wanted to make things interesting )

4 - You have the power of JavaScript, AngularJS, you name it, everything will be in javascript, so thats means that you can even port your web application ( in case you have such thing ) directly to your application.

5 - In case of an game, if you read or follow or searched over the nativescriot.org site you will come across this wonderfull article about incorpotaring games into your next application using Physics and even the accelerometer over here : https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/first-steps-in-game-dev-with-nativescript.

Comment: i have forgot to say one part of the app is a realtime audio analyse with fft, do you think native script is the right way with dsp?

Comment: @norbu please check the answers here, if they use any kind of native calls, you bet you can use it over nativescript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404828/android-audio-analysis-in-real-time