# Real-time audio capture and playback from an external mic

Tags: android

How can I capture audio from an external mic plugged in the 3.5mm jack and play it back in real-time to the phone speaker?

I'm able to capture the audio from that source, save it to a file and play it then to the speaker. However, when I try to mix the things, the audio is being captured from the in-built microphone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Repeated question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728454/playing-back-sound-coming-from-microphone-in-real-time)

Comment: @SPatali - that other question does not appear to have any relevance to the problem experienced here, but only to the part that seems to be already working.